# Increment CouchDB concurrent connections

Tags: connection, couchdb

I'm using CouchDB to serve thousands of requests per second. Sometimes it seems to respond slowly so I ran a small test with PHP and cURL, sending 1000 request at the same time (using `curl_multi`), and it takes up to 3 seconds, which is fine (although the server often receives way more requests than that). But if I increase the concurrent requests to 1010, Couch simply takes up to 300 seconds to respond to some of those requests. CPU usage doesn't go up much, it's like Couch isn't using enough resources to handle the heavy load.

I've tried rising the resources limit as described [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#Erlang) but that doesn't seem to work. The page says that Couch will `not allow more than 1024 connections by default`, but it seems to ignore the new settings and stays stuck at that default limit.

I need to figure out how to make CouchDB use as much system resources as it needs.

Comment: It looks like you're looking at the old documentation, I'd reference their [newest documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/maintenance/performance.html?highlight=performance) to get up-to-date information. (I didn't read through both and compare them, just thought I'd point out the newer resource)

Comment: May this apply to you? "Note that on Mac OS X, Erlang will not actually increase the file descriptor limit past 1024 (i.e. the system header–defined value of FD_SETSIZE). See this tip for a possible workaround and this thread for a deeper explanation."

Comment: @JuliusBeckmann Oh no, I'm using Ubuntu Server. Now what I found out is that CouchDB responds well with Apache Benchmark... and that would render this question as not-needed. I'll probably delete it in a moment. Thanks anyway!